# Information about public transport in Greece

Tags: online-resources, public-transport, greece

I'm going on a holiday to Greece tomorrow, and since I won't have a car over there I'm going to have to use public transport. After a bit of googling, I only found some vague descriptions about intercity buses, but nothing about timetables and prices.

So I was wondering if there is some sort of search engine or official website where I can find timetables and prices for buses in Greece. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm staying on the island of Zakynthos.

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14401/whats-the-best-way-to-travel-around-greece-train-or-bus http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19976/can-i-rely-on-public-transport-in-rhodes-greece-or-should-i-rent-a-car/19985#19985

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The magic words for looking up bus timetables in Greece are **ΚΤΕΛ** or **KTEL**. [This is what they are called.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%9A%CE%A4%CE%95%CE%9B)

So you can just Google the word KTEL plus the place one wants to go, et voila:

[`www.ktel-zakynthos.gr/schedules/local-routes`](http://www.ktel-zakynthos.gr/schedules/local-routes/)

Hope that helps. Enjoy your holidays!

Answer (score 0):

The main site that includes all the KTEL buses in Greece can be found [here](http://ktelbus.com/?module=default&pages_id=15) . From there you can search each district and get to the right schedule. Cheers!